# When a user changes the quantity in the NumericUpDown, how would the total price be displayed in the Total TextBox?

Tags: c#, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjHIP.png)

When a user changes the quantity in the NumericUpDown, how would the total price be displayed in the Total TextBox???

Answer (score 0):

In the Form Designer, right-click the NumericUpDown control and select properties. In properties, select the Events filter and double-click the ValueChanged event. You can put the code to do your calculation in this event method.

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalculateTotalPrice();
}
```